# Alert en MVC c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, mvc, alert

Tengo una duda, ¿Cómo muestro un alert en MVC?
Estoy validando desde el controlador lo siguiente:

```
var suscriptor = c.cargarDatosPDF(solicitud);
                if (suscriptor.Count <= 0)
                {
                    ViewBag.Alert = "Lo sentimos, esta solicitud no existe.";
                    return View("Index");
                }
```

Esa lista se carga con datos de `SQL`. Me gustaría que ese mensaje se vea en un `PopUp` o `Alert`, preferentemente en un `alert`. 
El `Index` posee un `TextBox` y un `Botón`.

Intenté usando:

```
alert(@ViewData["Mensaje"])
```

Pero, no ha funcionado. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

**Actualización:**

**Index:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Inicio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Estilos/inicio.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/JavaScript/validar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <div class="topnav" style="width: 350px">
            <a title="Providus S.A" href="http://www.providus.com.ar"><img src="~/Images/00.png" /></a>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 350px">
            <form method="post" action="@Url.Action("Pdf", "Home")">
                <label for="solicitud">Solicitud: </label>
                <input type="text" id="solicitud" minlength="5" maxlength="7" name="solicitud" placeholder="Solicitud..." required
                       title="Sólo letras y números. Cantidad mínima de caracteres: 5. Cantidad máxima de caracteres: 7"
                       onkeypress="return soloLetrasYnumeros(event)">

                <input type="submit" value="Buscar" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </center>
    @if (ViewBag.Alert != null)
    {
        <div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-info">
            <button type="submit" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
                &times;
            </button>
            <strong>Providus informa...</strong> @ViewBag.Alert
        </div>
    }
    @*<center>
        <p class="mensaje">@ViewData["Mensaje"]</p>
    </center>*@
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es un `alert()` simple de javascript, el ejemplo que ya te han puesto es válido, haciendo un pequeño cambio. En la vista, prueba a añadir este código:

```
@if (ViewBag.Alert != null)
{
  <script>
    alert("@ViewBag.Alert");
  </script>
}
```

Este código debería añadirse al final de la vista.

Comment: Gracias, esto es lo que buscaba específicamente.

Answer (score 2):

Primeramente la forma que propones de querer cambiar el mensaje del Alert box de javascript te informo que no se puede, si quieres un mensaje de alerta personalizado debes buscar una alternativa, una puede ser utilizando jQuery (https://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/)

Otra manera y más sencilla es definir en tu *Vista* o en el *_Layout* (vista compartida (Shared) de todas las vistas) un **ViewBag.Alert** e imprimiendo el mensaje necesario en cada caso.

```
 @if (ViewBag.Alert != null)
 {
     <div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-info">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
             &times;
         </button>
         <strong>Aviso!</strong> @ViewBag.Alert
     </div>
 }
```

Y en tu código C# le pasarías el siguiente mensaje:

```
var suscriptor = c.cargarDatosPDF(solicitud);
                if (suscriptor.Count <= 0)
                {
                    ViewBag.Alert = "Lo sentimos, esta solicitud no existe.";
                    return View("Index");
                }
```

Otra forma es utilizando un **Modal**(https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/), que ahí tendrías que usar algo de Javascript para hacer el muestreo.

Comment: Vale, lo he intentado pero el mensaje sigue saliendo en el `body` y lo que necesito es que salga como un `alert`

Comment: Bien, puedes implementar un modal; ya que a la funcion alert() de Javascript no le puedes cambiar el mensaje, eso viene predefinido.

Comment: Lo que yo quiero es que se vea así: [enlace](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-voxYLtYWCIQ/Wg5VSukBLgI/AAAAAAAAAWg/Qc974y1txiIQf0uFpG1N3LOWSfkS5EYcgCK4BGAYYCw/s1600/image-777925.png)

Pero se me ve así:  [enlace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uQsH.png)